# Reset Outlook PST password programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, pst

I am having trouble remembering my `Outlook PST` password, and cannot import that file into Outlook 2016. I have tried several forums, free password recovery software tools, but could not reset/recover the password. After browsing a lot, I found out `Aspose.Email` for `.NET` has a backdoor to access the properties of PST file and there's a way to reset password. I have no idea about this, and have never used `.NET` or `C#`. Is there someone who can help me out here?

Following are the related links from my browsing results:

Aspose.Email for .NET - https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-check-set-remove-or-update-password-of-pst

PST Password Property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385916(v=office.12).aspx

Please note my PST is UNICODE and not ANSI format, so following is already out of question.
http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/how-to-unlock-password-protected-pst-file-6

This is what I have tried online @https://dotnetfiddle.net/:

```
using System;
using Aspose.Email.Mapi;
using Aspose.Email.Storage.Pst;


namespace Aspose.Email.Examples.CSharp.Email.Outlook
{
    class RemovingPaswordProperty
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            // The path to the File directory.
            // ExStart:RemovingPaswordProperty
            string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_Outlook();
            PersonalStorage personalStorage = PersonalStorage.FromFile(dataDir + "PersonalStorage1.pst");
            if (personalStorage.Store.Properties.ContainsKey(MapiPropertyTag.PR_PST_PASSWORD))
            {
                MapiProperty property = new MapiProperty(MapiPropertyTag.PR_PST_PASSWORD, BitConverter.GetBytes((long)0));
                personalStorage.Store.SetProperty(property);
            }
            // ExEnd:RemovingPaswordProperty
        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting following errors:

`Error(s):
Compilation error (line 14, col 30): The name 'RunExamples' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: if you have no idea about c# - learning some basics would be your best bet

Comment: I have attempted to do that, and ran the code snippets online, but cannot figure out the errors. Its more than learning basics in this case.

Comment: then post your code and the errors - stackoverflow is not here to write it all for you

Comment: I have been answering a lot of question on SO myself, and I completely agree with you. But, I find it redundant, as the link already has code that I am referring/running.

Comment: If you want the help you will need to post the code and the errors

Comment: @BugFinder, hellyale - I was hesitating to put the code out, as the online compiler I was using earlier was showing the errors on each line when I was hovering my mouse on each statement. I didn't want to put a snapshot of that as that would be a bad practice. I found this other online compiler that is showing errors separately. Please help.

Comment: Thanks @hellyale, but I do not have admin rights on my machine. I have tried that already. Could you please take a look a the the updated code, and suggest anything?

Comment: Okay. I tried as suggested, and it seems all errors have been fixed. But I am getting `Fatal Error: Public Main() method is required in a public class`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error response.

Comment: I changed the `RemovingPaswordProperty` `class` to `public` too; and, receiving a run-time exception now. 

`Run-time exception (line -1): The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.

Stack Trace:

[System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.]

[System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.]`

.NET Fiddle Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yhau2e

Comment: Looks like it is not able to access the directory path due to security policies.

Comment: I was able to remove password from my PST using `Aspose.Email for Java` and can access my emails in Outlook. 

Reference:
https://github.com/aspose-email/Aspose.Email-for-Java

Comment: @Sagar,

Were you able to resolve the issue for .NET example? If no, please post us with your query on [Aspose.Email forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/email). We can provide you with a sample console application for example.

Comment: @KashifIqbal - Thanks for pointing me to the right forum. But, I was able to reset password using Aspose.Email for Java. It was a one-time problem, so not looking for any further solutions at this point of time.